# can sys.exit() be made to exit bottle framework

Tags: python, bottle

I was hoping that putting 'sys.exit(1)' and catching it later like this will work.

```
xml_open()
try:
  run(reloader=True, host='localhost', port=8080)
except SystemExit:
  xml_save()
  print "Exited ..."
```

Is there any other solution to exit these python micro-frameworks to exit from inside
the handlers ?

Answer (score 1):

If its not being handled then check whether Its really executes sys.exist(1) statement,
because It may happen some other exception raised which is not being handled try this....

```
xml_open()
try:
  run(reloader=True, host='localhost', port=8080)
except SystemExit:
  xml_save()
  print "Exited ..."
except Exception, e:
  print "ohhh no.......",str(e)
  import pdb
  pdb.post_mortem()
  sys.exit(-1)
```

Comment: sys.exit() raises SystemExit .. it'll not raise any other exception. See http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.exit

Comment: I mean check whether its getting called or not !

Comment: oh ok .. actually problem here is with so many layers of fn calls and try-except ... some thing eats up the exception .. there seems to be some handling being done , but it's coming to my exception handler at all.

Comment: I've updated the code and added pdb so you can trace the error, from which layer its get exhausted...

Answer (score 1):

In case this is still an issue for you, check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11282218/bottle-web-framework-how-to-stop/16056443#16056443) for a clean solution of stopping the bottle framework.

Answer (score 0):

From my limited experience, `sys.exit()` should work when reloader is turned off. Otherwise, reloader will reload the code on `sys.exit()` and your application will be resumed. Of course, I might be wrong about why `sys.exit()` doesn't work, but for me it worked when I turned off the reloader.